# jQuery append not working with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

My jQuery append function isn't working. I have a div with a class called "CollapsiblePanelContent". I also have a google maps marker generator that generates the markers for me. I have an array markerArr that contains all the marker info from a XML. When the generator is done i call a function appendMarkers():

```
function appendMarkers() {   
for(var i = 0; i < markersArr.length;
i++) {      
var marker = markersArr[i];

$('.CollapsiblePanelContent').append("<a href='#'
onclick='showInfoWindow("+i+")>
 "+marker.getAttribute('name')+"</a><br>");     
} 
}
```

The div looks like this:

div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">

/div>

Console logging gave me the exact length of the markerArr, and checking if google maps and jquery are loaded were both positive.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Somehow it didn't work when i used marker.getAttribute in my function.
But when i did the following:

```
var name = markersArr[i].getAttribute("name")
```

And editted the following to:

```
$('.CollapsiblePanelContent').append(name);
```

It did work.
For me it is not clear why this change made it work. Maybe that someone could explain?

Comment: `google.maps.Markers` doesn't have a method `getAttribute`

Comment: Edited my question. markerArr is an converted XML array. And that does have a function getAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function contains syntax-errors.

Use the jQuery-way instead of string-concatenation to create the element:

```
      function appendMarkers() {

        for(var i = 0; i < markersArr.length; i++) {      
          var marker = markersArr[i];

          $('.CollapsiblePanelContent')
            .append($('<a>',{href:'javascript:void(0)'})
                    .text(marker.getAttribute('name'))
                     .click(i,showInfoWindow))
            .append('<br/>');    
          } 
        }
```

Note: in `showInfoWindow` the `i`-argument may be accessed via `arguments[0].data`

Comment: Very helpfull, and thanks for pointing me to arguments.data. Never knew about this. I will accept your anwser since you gave me an explanation.

Comment: when you use `$.click` (or other events) to assign listeners to objects, you may optionally pass as first argument something custom that will be set to the event-arguments(first argument of the handler) data-property.

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to the marker object. Once you retrieve it, you can access them. So:

Supposing your markers are set up this way:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                name: 'my name is...'
});
```

You can retrieve the name in your function this way:

```
function appendMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markersArr.length; i++) {
        var marker = markersArr[i];
        $('.CollapsiblePanelContent').append("<p>"+marker.name+"</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The markerArr is actually a XML file converted to an array. But thanks for your tip!

Comment: btw, update your question with the xml and the method to parse it if you need any help.

Comment: To be clear: I dont need any helping parsing. I just need to know why my append function isnt working. Every jQuery functions work but not append

Comment: @andy if you are creating the markers as I said in my answer, the way of accesing the attribute is the one  I showed. It also should append to CollapsiblePanelContent the name of each marker.